# focus() on Select field fired before Ember updates disabledBinding attribute

Tags: ember.js

In my application I have an extended `Em.Select` view:

```
App.SelectField = Em.Select.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['disabled'],
    actions: {
        setFocus: function(){
            this.$().focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Which is used in my handlebar template:

```
{{view App.SelectField 
    viewName="cbAddressType"
    disabledBinding='getIsDisabled'
    contentBinding="controllers.addressTypes"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.addressTypeName"
    valueBinding="getSetAddressType"}}
```

The view has a `disabledBinding` bound to the view's controller property `getIsDisabled`. When this property changes, the Select view is either enabled or disabled. This works just fine.

However, I also have an action on the template:

```
<button {{action "editRecord" view.cbAddressType}}>Edit</button>
```

This calls the controller's `editRecord` action:

```
actions: {
    editRecord: function (fieldToFocusOn) {
            this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
            if (fieldToFocusOn  && this.get('isEditing'))
            {
                fieldToFocusOn.send("setFocus");
            }
    }
}
```

Which sends the `setFocus` action to the above `SelectField`, which in turn runs the `focus()` method on the select control.

The problem is that `focus()` is fired BEFORE the `disabledBinding` attribute on the Select is updated with the bound property's changed value in the controller. The control cannot receive the focus until it is enabled. I tried a `while select.disabled [wait] loop` but that just led to an infinite loop as it appears that the view is not refreshed until after the `setFocus` is called - they are not run asynchronously.

What I also note is that on a `Ember.TextField` with a `readonlyBinding` instead of a `disabledBinding` that this methodology works fine: the text field's `readonly` attribute is removed before the focus() event is fired.

Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but could work. In your `App.SelectField` use:

```
setFocus: function(){
  Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() {
    this.$().focus();
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. added 'Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() {$(this.elementId).focus();});' but .focus() is still being triggered before the Select has had its disabled attribute removed. any more ideas??

Comment: oops, sorry, that does work. In one of my various attempts at a solution I had put a #if into the template, displaying a different select depending on variable isEditing state - so the element changed between before and after render - therefore it was attempting to focus() on a control that no longer existed! So thanks, this works..although why I need to do this for a Select and not an Input element, I don't know!

Comment: Ember have some queues, and the `afterRender` is called after the view is rendered. I don't know why this problem just happen in the select ... If my answer solved your problem, please accept it. Otherwise write your aproach, so users with the same problem, can have some reference. Thanks!